# Unable to send email using app engine mail package?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform

I am new to AppEngine and golang and trying to send an email by using below code and but I do not receive any mail. Cloud you please help to fix it.

Now I am running this code directly from app engine, how to test it from local development server :
***Edited1:***
When I am running from local development

```
dev_appserver.py --smtp_host=smtp.gmail.com --smtp_port=25
--smtp_user=venkatanagarajas@gmail.com --smtp_password=****** E:\GoWork\src\email\appenginemail
```

I am getting below error:

```
 From: venkatanagarajas@gmail.com
To: Srinadh <kasireddy002@gmail.com>
      Subject: See you tonight
      Body:
        Content-type: text/plain
        Data length: 41
    ERROR    2018-02-02 00:17:00,318 api_server.py:407] Exception while handling mail.Send()
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py", line 375, in _handle_POST
        api_response = _execute_request(request).Encode()
      File "C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py", line 231, in _execute_request
        make_request()
      File "C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\api_server.py", line 226, in make_request
        request_id)
      File "C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub.py", line 151, in MakeSyncCall
        method(request, response)
      File "C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 311, in _Send
        self._SendSMTP(mime_message, smtp_lib)
      File "C:\Program Files\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\mail_stub.py", line 233, in _SendSMTP
        smtp.sendmail(mime_message['From'], tos, mime_message.as_string())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 744, in sendmail
        senderrs[each] = (code, resp)
    TypeError: unhashable instance
```

Running this code from local development server and also AppEngine

```
package app

import (
    "net/http"

    "google.golang.org/appengine"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/log"
    "google.golang.org/appengine/mail" )

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/sendmail", handleIndex) }

func handleIndex(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    ctx := appengine.NewContext(req)

    msg := &mail.Message{
        Sender: "venkatanagarajas@gmail.com",
        To: []string{"Srinadh <kasireddy002@gmail.com>"},
        Subject: "See you tonight",
        Body: "Don't forget our plans. Hark, 'til later.",
    }
    if err := mail.Send(ctx, msg); err != nil {
        log.Errorf(ctx, "Alas, my user, the email failed to sendeth: %v", err)
    } }
```

Comment: I don't know about the error about runing on GAE, but about testing emails local, GAE has a document: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server. It is in the **using mail** part

Comment: @leafbebop I have tried the same but getting the above error

Answer (score 0):

GAE is not run on the local server, you have to configure SMTP locally and invoked their methods

Steps:

1. Install SMTP locally (https://www.gazblog.com/2016/07/install-ssmtp-and-setup-with-gmail-on-ubuntu-16-04/)
2. Add this code to send the mail (https://medium.com/@dhanushgopinath/sending-html-emails-using-templates-in-golang-9e953ca32f3d)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)